# Get absolute url for a file in my asp.net project to include HTTP// etc for use externally?

Tags: asp.net

been playing around with ResolveClientUrl("~/Confirmation.aspx")  and other methods..

I am tryin go get the FULL absolute URL of the page including Http: etc etc..

Anyone knows how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Request.Url.ToString()
```

gets the absolute URL for the current request.

If you want to get it for a relative path:

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) 
                      + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(relativePath)
```

Comment: but this gets the full url of the page.. need to get the base and using ~Nameofpage.aspx to append it

Comment: -1: This only works if the page you want a handle to is the page you're operating in the context of right now.

Comment: @mark: There's no direct method to do that. That's your best bet.

Comment: @DDaviesBrackett: I updated the answer to handle that case too.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the url up to the root of the asp.net application (including virtual folders in IIS).  From there you can just append the relative path of the file you want to reference

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, string.Empty) +
    HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;

if (!url.EndsWith("/")) url += "/";

url += "path/to/myfile.jpeg";
```

Comment: Path.Combine for a virtual path? Good luck with that.

Comment: Sorry, spazzed out with Path.Combine.  Fixed

Comment: In any case, the meat of the answer is using Url.AbsolutePath and Request.ApplicationPath.  That will work fine