# How does Response.Redirect calculate the URL for "~/folder1/folder2/some.aspx"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, api, uri

This might *sound* like a trivial problem but for some reason it is not.

Instead of needing to redirect

```
Response.Redirect("~/folder1/folder2/some.aspx")
```

I need the location as if it behaved like

```
string navigatingUrl = Response.Redirect("~/folder1/folder2/some.aspx")
```

Trying to replicate this I started with

```
string navigatingUrl = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url,
                     new Uri("~/folder1/folder2/some.aspx", UriKind.Relative));
```

This instead generates `"http://www.fullRequestUrl/~/folder1/folder2/some.aspx"`

**Edit:** Well I've found out why I absolutely hate the URL API from Microsoft. I wish hellfire to whoever wrote this line of code

```
else if (uriKind == UriKind.Relative) 
{
// Here we know that we can create an absolute Uri, but the user has requested 
    only a relative one
e = GetException(ParsingError.CannotCreateRelative);
}
```

What would possess someone to throw an error like that? This single if statement completely destroys the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stealing from [Get absolute url for a file in my asp.net project to include HTTP// etc for use externally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095394/get-absolute-url-for-a-file-in-my-asp-net-project-to-include-http-etc-for-use-e) the only absolute way to do this is:

```
string url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) 
                    + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(relativePath)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for [Control.ResolveUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx).  Typically you would probably use the method found on your Page object (if you are using WebForms).

Comment: Something feels very wrong with having to code `using(var c = new Control()) url = c.ResolveUrl(input)` inside of an API that has no coupling to controls of any sort.

Comment: Are you using WebForms? If so, you could always create an IUrlResolver interface to your Page class (which requires the ResolveUrl() method) and then pass your Page into your API (using the interface to limit exposure and allow easy replacement).  Unfortunately, I think the only alternatives are going to be equally ugly; Probably best alternative is to write your own replacement code (check reflector for implementation of the ResolveUrl()) method.

Comment: It really makes no sense why .NET has the url API so completely shrouded in secrecy.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect(Page.ResolveUrl("~/folder1/forlder2/some.aspx"), false);
```

Comment: If I want use tilde symbol in the Response.Redirect  I have found it needs to be resolved.
My expectations are that it resolves to the app base directory and not the site directory.
://localhost.myApp/ (this one)  VS  ://localhost/